# Laravel SSL redirect loop with Nginx

Tags: php, redirect, nginx, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am setting up SSL to protect my mydomain.com/admin area, I'm on Nginx with Laravel, SSL is working, as in if I go to https://www.mydomain.com it works. But, my attempts at redirecting get a "This web page has a redirect loop" error.

I have the following filter setup in Laravel

```
Route::filter('secure', function () {
  if (! Request::secure()) {
      return Redirect::secure(
          Request::path(),
          in_array(Request::getMethod(), ['POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE']) ? 307 : 302
      );
  }
});
```

And am successfully routing to it with:

```
Route::when('admin/*', 'secure');
```

And this is my Nginx config:

```
server {

    listen       80;
    server_name  DOMAIN.com;
    return       301 http://www.DOMAIN.com$request_uri;

}

server {

    listen 80;

    listen 443;
    ssl on;

    server_name www.DOMAIN.com;

    ssl_certificate      /srv/ssl/www.DOMAIN.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /srv/ssl/www.DOMAIN.com.key;

    access_log /srv/www/www.DOMAIN.com/logs/access.log;

    error_log /srv/www/www.DOMAIN.com/logs/error.log;
    root /srv/www/www.DOMAIN.com/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

      fastcgi_param  HTTPS  off;
      fastcgi_read_timeout  500;
    }

}
```

Many thanks....

Comment: There is no point in doing the redirect in nginx config and having it setup in the fancy Laravel application. Choose one.

Comment: Am I redirecting in Nginx? Only http://example.com to http://www.example.com?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is because I had

```
fastcgi_param  HTTPS  off;
```

Have changed to

```
fastcgi_param  HTTPS  on;
```

And everything is working fine